# VisualRuby and DevKit setup

Tags: ruby, user-interface, rubygems, desktop-application

I want to create a desktop application in ruby using visualruby. I need the devkit so I followed [these instructions](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit)

1. I installed ruby 2.0.0 and glade3-3.6.7-with-GTK+
2. Opened up CMD window, navigated to `C:\Ruby200-x64\bin`
3. Typed `ruby 'C:\DevKit\dk.rb' init` which made a `config.yml` inside `C:\Ruby200-x64\bin`
4. Opened `config.yml` in notepad and added `- C:/Ruby200-x64` at the end, saved and closed
5. Typed `ruby 'C:\DevKit\dk.rb' install` and it spat out

   [INFO] Installing 'C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/defaults/operating_systems.rb'
   [INFO] Installing 'C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/devkit.rb'
6. Finally, typed `gem install visualruby` and it said 
   [image]

Any ideas on how to fix this and get visualruby working?

Comment: Seems like you should install `glade` and `gtk` libs first: http://www.visualruby.net/site/Download.html

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev that's the weird part, I already did that. I'm even messing around in Glade 3.6.7 as we speaking, just making some windows....Should I remove it and reinstall?

Comment: Actually I don't know. I just see that installation can't find gobject-2.0 lib and this is Gnome's lib which should be installed together with gtk and glade. If you installed all these libs the problem could be in ruby that it can't locate them.

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev so any ideas on solutions then?

Comment: I don't have windows os on computer right now. Will try to do it tomorrow if you don't find an answer...

Comment: I've installed VisualRuby by instructions at http://www.visualruby.net/site/Download.html It works. The only difference to you: I use ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev holy crap that worked, thank you so much!! I have no idea why the latest version of ruby *wouldn't* work but whatever, it works now. Thanks! Please post the answer so I can approve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've installed VisualRuby directed by instructions at http://visualruby.net/site/Download.html It works just fine. I use ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of visualruby works with ruby 2.3.0 in Windows.  Widows had a few problems with ciaro, but its been fixed by version 2.3.0.